# Stroking rect background

Tags: pdfbox

I've recently updated PDFBox to version 2.0.0 (for its new images methods) but they've changed the way you fill a rect.

Previously you would addRect, set the stroking color and struck, set the non-stroking color and fill the rect.

Now the fillRect has been replaced with fill and I'm unable to stroke and fill. Calling stroking after filling will do nothing and vice-versa.

Now I'm forced to call addRect for a second time to get the desired effect.

Any help with updating my method?

Comment: Basically my "solution" is exactly what was done previously in version 1.8 and as mkl has said my previous code was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Previously you would addRect, set the stroking color and struck

... and in doing so create an invalid PDF! Between the start of path creation (here: `addRect`) and its drawing (here: `stroke`), only additional path creation operations and eventually optionally a clipping path operation are allowed. Your setting the stroking color in-between is invalid.

Most PDF viewers don't complain about this invalid syntax but it is invalid nonetheless...

---

> Now the fillRect has been replaced with fill and I'm unable to stroke and fill.

`fillRect` still is there and merely has been deprecated. Thus, you can look what it does:

```
public void fillRect(float x, float y, float width, float height) throws IOException
{
    if (inTextMode)
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Error: fillRect is not allowed within a text block.");
    }
    addRect(x, y, width, height);
    fill();
}
```

Thus, if you used to do

```
setStrokingColor(...);
addRect(...);
stroke();
setNonStrokingColor(...);
fillRect(...);
```

in PDFBox 1.8.x, you can do the same in 2.0.0 or (to not use deprecated methods) replace the last line by

```
addRect(...);
fill();
```

> Now I'm forced to call addRect for a second time to get the desired effect.

But that is what you under the hood used to do before, too!

**PS** Recently two new operations have been added to PDFBox' `PDPageContentStream` class: `fillAndStroke`, `fillAndStrokeEvenOdd`, `closeAndFillAndStroke`, and `closeAndFillAndStrokeEvenOdd`. Thus, now you can also use

```
setStrokingColor(...);
setNonStrokingColor(...);
addRect(...);
fillAndStroke();
```

Comment: I see. And it's normal to have to add 2 rects to do what's accounts for 1 operation?

Comment: @DMH Actually pdf knows a stroke&fill operation which I don't find modeled here in PdfBox. It's fairly harmless to repeat a simple rectangle definition but other paths can be much more complicated.

Comment: I'll create methods for the B, B*, b and b* operators so you'll be able to do it with 1 operation.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Great. In case of complex paths that really makes sense!